# which jdk to use for android sdk?

Tags: java, android, linux

i am using openjdk in my Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit. but i am unable to create the AVD with SD card and when created the AVD without SD card i akm unable to launch simple hello world program in emulator. so is that the problem with the jdk? 
Please somebody help me.

Comment: Did you follow [these directions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#troubleshooting) for setting up a 64-bit Ubuntu Linux environment?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem regarding the hello world program is not associated the jdk. Android does not use jdk for any of its programming (It does need it for installing the SDK to begin with). Android has its own API library.

For information on how to create a simple hello world program, please view the link below.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Comment: why i am unable to create AVD with SD card given size. i have tried everything but failed

Comment: Walk me through how you are creating the AVD with SD card.

Comment: Yes it does. The Oracle JDK is even listed in the system requirements: http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

Comment: @eldarerathis - you are correct in saying that it is needed for development. However, I assumed since he was able to install the SDK and is now moving onto the programming aspect, he is referring to the libraries, in which case Android uses its own set.

Comment: @Otra: Okay, I see what you were trying to say with that statement. I originally interpreted it as a claim that the JDK was simply not needed.

Comment: @eldarerathis Good catch, I'll edit my answer accordingly to make it less misleading.

Comment: @Otra : I have installed the API level 8 and tried to create the AVD with name AVD2.2, and SD Card Size 512 and chose the default display. but when i press create it says Failed to create. I am using the Open JDK,Eclipse Indigo on 64 bit Ubuntu 11.04. So any help?? pleaseee